# MySQL Wordpress database: How to find users who have not posted since a number of weeks, as I can't use max(date) in select clause?

Tags: sql, mysql, wordpress, subquery, inner-join

Here is what I am at right now, but it does not return anything

```
select wp_users.user_nicename, wp_users.user_email, max(yearweek(wp_wpforo_posts.created)) as w
from LeBearCNC.wp_users, wp_wpforo_posts
where wp_users.ID = wp_wpforo_posts.userid
and not exists (select max(yearweek(wp_wpforo_posts.created)) where wp_users.ID = wp_wpforo_posts.userid) /*and yearweek(current_date()) - 12 < yearweek(wp_wpforo_posts.created))*/
group by wp_users.user_nicename, wp_users.user_email
order by w desc;
```

if I put the max(yearweek(wp_wpforo_posts.created)) in the where clause, I get an error "invalid use of group function"

Forgot to precise that wp_wpforo tables are for a forum plugin named wpForo

I managed to get what I want, using a temporary table, but I believe I should be able to bypass the need for this temporary table. I just don't know how:

```
     create temporary table if not exists lastpost as 
(select wp_wpforo_posts.userid,max(date(wp_wpforo_posts.created)) as w
from wp_wpforo_posts
group by userid);

SELECT wp_users.display_name, wp_users.user_email, lastpost.w
from wp_users, lastpost
where lastpost.userid = wp_users.ID
and date_add(lastpost.w, interval 6 month) < date(current_date())
order by w desc;
```

Thanks for you help,
Bernard.

Comment: I managed to get the results I wanted, using a temporary table. I believe I should be able to bypass the need for this temporary table, but I don't know how.

Comment: every subselect, every Cte, every join makes temptables, so your approach with external emptables can be manged by the code, but with out seeing data, it is very hard to tell, if their is a better apporach see  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

you can use subqueries as temporary tabels and notice is use standrd sql JOIN for my queries, as this is standrad nowadays

```
SELECT wp_users.display_name, wp_users.user_email, lastpost.w
from wp_users JOIN (select wp_wpforo_posts.userid,max(date(wp_wpforo_posts.created)) as w
from wp_wpforo_posts
group by userid) lastpost
ON lastpost.userid = wp_users.ID
WHERE date_add(lastpost.w, interval 6 month) < current_date()
order by w desc;
```

Comment: `date(current_date())`  

Comment: super, then accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use this query

```
SELECT u.user_nicename,
       u.user_email,
       MAX(YEARWEEK(p.created)) AS w
FROM   lebearcnc.wp_users u 
         INNER JOIN wp_wpforo_posts p ON u.id = p.userid
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   wp_wpforo_posts p1
                   WHERE  p1.userid = u.id
                          AND YEARWEEK(p1.created) > YEARWEEK(current_date()) - 12)
GROUP  BY u.user_nicename, u.user_email
ORDER  BY w DESC;
```

Comment: Sorry, I have not tested this as @nbk gave me a good answer, but I am quite sure it is another possibility. Thank you, guys !

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is more efficient to use a subquery to retrieve the date of the latest post. Probably you have few users and many posts, so you would rather use correlation to retrieve the information you want rather than to `group by` over a large dataset, then `join`.

If you are running a recent version of MySQL, this is good spot to use a lateral join:

```
select u.user_nicename, u.user_email, p.last_created
from wp_users u 
cross join lateral (
    select max(p.created) last_created from wp_wpforo_posts p where u.id = p.userid
) p
where p.last_created < current_date - interval 6 month
order by p.last_created;
```

In earlier versions, we can use an inline subquery, and add another layer to filter:

```
select *
from (
    select u.user_nicename, u.user_email, 
        (select max(p.created) from wp_wpforo_posts p where u.id = p.userid) last_created
    from wp_users u 
) u
where last_created < current_date - interval 6 month
order by last_created;
```

For performance, consider an index on `wp_wpforo_posts(userid, created)`, or better yet `wp_wpforo_posts(userid, created desc)`.